# Definite integrals steps help?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**So while doing  a long and complicated Fourier transform, I need to do this integral.I need the steps to the final answer please.**

$F(w) = \lim_{T1 \to ∞}\{-{\int_{-T1}^0 [t e^{-jwt}]\,dt } + \int_0^{T1} [t e^{-jwt}]\,dt \}$

The result in my book is  $F(w)=2/w^2$

Comment: Is it $T_1$ or $T$ ?

Comment: Just to start you off; that limit does not exist in the conventional sense as the definite integral evaluates to: $$2\,{\frac {{\it T1}\,\sin \left( w{\it T1} \right) }{w}}+2\,{\frac {
\cos \left( w{\it T1} \right) }{{w}^{2}}}-2\,\dfrac{1}{w^2}$$
You need to use the distributional derivative and law 310 on the Wikipedia [Fourier Transfrom][1] page (but deriving that is beyond me I'm afraid...)


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform